# Snowflake Stored Procedures to generate unique IDs and then insert values into a table

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, procedure

I am using Snowflake stored procedures to try and log errors as they occur. The current stored proc has an if/else statement, but I'm just trying to get one section working for now since the code is the more or less the same with variations to the SQL statements.

```
create or replace Procedure PLog(
    PName varchar,
    CName varchar,
    PType varchar)
returns varchar
not null
language javascript

AS
$$
var cyc_id_sql = `SELECT case when count(CycleId) > 0 then max(CycleID) + 1 else 1 end as CycleId from SCHEMA.TABLE1 where CycleName='${CName}'`;
var cycle_id_create = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: cyc_id_sql});
var cycleid = cycle_id_create.execute();
var p_id_sql = `Select case when count(ProcessId) > 0 then max(ProcessID) + 1 else 1 end as ProcessId from SCHEMA.TABLE2 where ProcessName='${PName}'`;
var p_id_create = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: p_id_sql});
var processid = p_id_create.execute();
var insertValuesText = `INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE
           (
            ProcessLogId
           ,CycleId
           ,ProcessId
           ,CycleName
           ,ProcessName
           ,ProcessType
           ,ProcessStatus
           ,StartTime)
     VALUES
           (default,${cycleid},${processid},'${value3}','${value4}','${value5}','Started',current_timestamp )`;

var insertValues = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: insertValuesText});
insertValues.execute();
$$
```

When I call this I get the error:

```
SQL compilation error: syntax error line 12 at position 28 unexpected 'Object'. syntax error line 12 at position 44 unexpected 'Object'. At Statement.execute, line 22 position 13
```

I  think the issue is that the cycle and process statements create a Javascript object instead of the desired value. The desired value being the unique ID. When I run the SQL separately with an empty database I get 1, which is expected so I know the SELECT statements work. When I run and then call:

```
create or replace Procedure PLog(
    PName varchar,
    CName varchar,
    PType varchar)
returns varchar
not null
language javascript

AS
$$
var cyc_id_sql = `SELECT case when count(CycleId) > 0 then max(CycleID) + 1 else 1 end as CycleId from SCHEMA.TABLE1 where CycleName='${CName}'`;
var cycle_id_create = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: cyc_id_sql});
var cycleid = cycle_id_create.execute();
return cycleid
$$
```

I get [object Object]. I'm not that familiar with JavaScript so any help would be appreciated. I think the issue is that my variables generate instances of an object instead of a usable value for the SQL statement, I just don't know how to fix the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you execute a statement `var processid = p_id_create.execute();` processid is the result set, not the actual value you want. you need to fetch it

so here is some [example](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-javascript.html#binding-variables) from the doc's

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE right_bind(TIMESTAMP_VALUE VARCHAR)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
var cmd = "SELECT CURRENT_DATE() > TO_TIMESTAMP(:1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')";
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
          {
          sqlText: cmd,
          binds: [TIMESTAMP_VALUE]
          }
          );
var result1 = stmt.execute();
result1.next();
return result1.getColumnValue(1);
$$
;
```

so your small example should be:

```
create or replace Procedure PLog(
    PName varchar,
    CName varchar,
    PType varchar)
returns varchar
not null
language javascript

AS
$$
var cyc_id_sql = `SELECT case when count(CycleId) > 0 then max(CycleID) + 1 else 1 end as CycleId from SCHEMA.TABLE1 where CycleName='${CName}'`;

var cycle_id_create = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: cyc_id_sql});
var result1 = cycle_id_create.execute();
result1.next();
var cycleid  result1.getColumnValue(1);
return cycleid
$$
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that it's returning a JavaScript object. As Simeon notes, this is returning a resultSet. If you're expecting a query to return a scalar (single row with a single column) you can use inline code to get it. However, it will not be modular and harder to read than modular code. This is a great example of where a helper function helps.

For example:

```
create or replace procedure TEST()
returns string
language javascript
as
$$

var my_scalar = getScalar("select C_NAME from SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1.CUSTOMER limit 1");

return my_scalar;

function getScalar(sql){
    cmd = {sqlText: sql};
    stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd);
    var rs;
    rs = stmt.execute();
    rs.next();
    return rs.getColumnValue(1);
}

$$;
```

You can then use the `getScalar` helper function to collect scalar values you need. If you're only doing it once it won't matter too much. If you're collecting a few or dozens, then it will keep the code modular, compact, and more readable.

Comment: good suggestion regarding keeping the code clean..